# request.getAttribute in javascript shows null

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am executing a query in jsp and using `resultSet.getString()` to get that field.

```
String eKnowledge = resultset.getString("knowledge");
```

Then using `request.setAttribute()` to set that field in jsp.

```
request.setAttribute("actualKnowledge", eKnowledge);
```

I am using `request.getAttribute()` in javascript to get that object.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    function moreInformationDisplay() {
        var jsKnowledge = <%=request.getAttribute("actualKnowledge")%>;
        alert(jsKnowledge); 
    }

</script>
```

But the alert message shows **null**. 
Can someone please help me with this problem.

Comment: `<%=request.getAttribute("actualKnowledge")%>` - this is pre-processed on the server side before the page is loaded into the browser - are you hoping for some magic two way communication between server and client without using AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

If your javaScript block is inserted in a valid JSP page, after the call to .setAttribute and resultset.getString("knowledge") is not null, then your code should work fine.

However this is bad practice and should be avoided.
You should be using JSTL
[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Your code could also be vunerable to XSS injection, if eKnowledge contains user input. It would be a good idea to escape it with a tool like [OWASP Java encoder](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project#tab=Use_the_Java_Encoder_Project)

Comment: javaScript block is inside the same JSP page.

Comment: Can you output <%= eKnowledge %> in your jsp and see what it outputs, when rendred to HTML?

Comment: eKnowledge prints the value which is stored in database.

Comment: Try to add some quotes before and after the expression:var jsKnowledge = "<%=request.getAttribute("actualKnowledge")%>";

Comment: Tried that.. no success